# Expected object or value error while reading json file in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

```
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/gbd.json'
df = pd.read_json(path)
```

`this is the error I am getting.`

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-3e269770844d> in <module>()
      1 path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/gbd.json'
----> 2 df = pd.read_json(path)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
   1138         if orient == "columns":
   1139             self.obj = DataFrame(
-> 1140                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
   1141             )
   1142         elif orient == "split":

ValueError: Expected object or value
```

I have tried all the following solutions

```
data= pd.read_json('Data.json', lines=True)

data= pd.read_json('Data.json', lines=True, orient='records')

data= pd.read_json('Data.json', orient=str)
```

this is the link to the json file
https://ccewuksprdoneregsadata1.blob.core.windows.net/data/json/publicextract.charity.zip
I want to create a dataframe from the json file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you consider the possibility that the problem is with the contents of the file, rather than with the code? You say you "want to create a dataframe" from that data; but how should we know what that dataframe should look like? Most people are not willing to download a zip file from the Internet in order to test someone else's code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to figure out what exactly is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is not well formatted. Try:

```
with open('publicextract.charity.json', encoding='utf-8-sig') as fp:
    data = json.loads(''.join(line.strip() for line in fp))

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

Output:

```
            date_of_extract  organisation_number  registered_charity_number  linked_charity_number                        charity_name  ... cio_is_dissolved date_cio_dissolution_notice charity_activities charity_gift_aid charity_has_land
0       2022-02-02T00:00:00                    1                     200027                      1     POTTERNE MISSION ROOM AND TRUST  ...             None                        None               None             None             None
1       2022-02-02T00:00:00                    2                     200027                      2                 HITCHAM FREE CHURCH  ...             None                        None               None             None             None
2       2022-02-02T00:00:00                    3                     200028                      1     TOWN LANDS CHARITY FOR THE POOR  ...             None                        None               None             None             None
3       2022-02-02T00:00:00                    4                     200028                      2   TOWN LANDS CHARITY FOR THE CHURCH  ...             None                        None               None             None             None
4       2022-02-02T00:00:00                    5                     200034                      1     CLOPHILL RELIEF IN NEED CHARITY  ...             None                        None               None             None             None
...                     ...                  ...                        ...                    ...                                 ...  ...              ...                         ...                ...              ...              ...
376732  2022-02-02T00:00:00              5193574                    1197688                      0      FEN DRAYTON PRIMARY SCHOOL PTA  ...            False                        None               None             None             None
376733  2022-02-02T00:00:00              5193708                    1197741                      0  BOLSOVER C OF E JUNIOR SCHOOL FROG  ...            False                        None               None             None             None
376734  2022-02-02T00:00:00              5193765                    1197681                      0         ST MICHAEL'S RC PRIMARY PTA  ...            False                        None               None             None             None
376735  2022-02-02T00:00:00              5193830                    1197732                      0              THE LIGHTHOUSE, DARWEN  ...            False                        None               None             None             None
376736  2022-02-02T00:00:00              5193998                    1197750                      0               THE PENDLE FOUNDATION  ...            False                        None               None             None             None

[376737 rows x 34 columns]
```

Comment: It's working good. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i was able to make a DataFrame with a small extract of your file and the problem was that there is a small unvisible group of char before the beginning of the file, which somehow blocks it. It wouldn't be visible to all editors and it was s pure luck that I tested it with different editors. This char looks something like **ï»¿**, try to open it with different editors and to delete it and it will work.

Comment: That is the UTF-8 encoding of a byte order mark. This [has caused problems before](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=json+byte+order+mark). [See also](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20598).

Comment: Thank for your answer, I never thought this could be the problem.

Comment: @GaneshGhadge. It's not a problem after all. Can you check my answer, please?